# bash Interrupted system call

Tags: bash, fifo

Ive got "Interrupted system call" message and dont really know why to be honest. My homework is to write server script who uses fifo to communicate with client script, basically it works but I dont know how to get rid of this message. Will appreciate for any suggestion.

My server script:

```
#!/bin/bash

server=serwerfifo

if [[ "$1" ]]; then
    if [[ ! -p $1 ]]; then
        echo "Reader(klient) not running"
    else
        echo $(expr $2 + $2) > $1 &
    fi
else
    trap "" SIGHUP SIGTERM SIGCHLD
    trap "exit 0" SIGUSR1

    if [[ ! -p $server ]]; then
        mkfifo $server
    fi

    while true
    do
        if read line < $server; then
            $0 $line &
        fi
    done
fi
```

Message appears when interpreter rich this line:

```
if read line < $server; then
```

Comment: http://shellcheck.net/ is your friend (not for the EINTR issue, but in general -- you've got a lot of bugs in here it'll catch).

Comment: BTW, is it intentional that you're re-opening your FIFO for each individual read? That's not generally good practice.

Comment: It was't my intention obviously, this is my firs steps in concurrency programing :)

Answer (score 2):

With respect to the EINTR -- you're making your code unnecessarily prone to race conditions by re-opening the FIFO repeatedly. Don't do that more often than you have to -- use a single handle until the writer closes (and thus you get an EOF).

```
while :; do # if we hit end-of-FIFO, then loop around and try to reopen
  while read -r line; do
    "$0" "$line" &
  done < "$server"
done
```

Note that the `< "$server"` is **on the loop**, not on the `read`, so if you have multiple lines written by your writer, those multiple lines will be read by the reader before it closes the FIFO.

---

The other pertinent thing here is your use of background processes making events asynchronous (and thus their ordering non-deterministic). You *really can* get a completely legitimately interrupted syscall, particularly when you have open and close operations happening at hard-to-predict times: a UNIX kernel is *allowed* to tell userland that it needs to retry what it's doing (and that another attempt will succeed). That's not an error, it's a legitimate and permissible result.

Comment: You're completely right with non-deterministic situations as this is it what we are dealing with now, thats the point we have to avoid this situation when working with multiple processes in background.

Comment: If you want deterministic behavior, well, that's what locking is for. Would you consider an answer showing you how to use `flock` to be what you were looking for?

Comment: @dimon, ...the other thing is, though, that per POSIX semantics, the kernel is allowed to return EINTR *whenever it wants to*. In theory, it could happen even with none of the asynchrony/concurrency involved -- so if you write your code to assume it'll only ever happen under the circumstances when it *currently* is observed to happen, you're writing fragile code. Better to assume only what the API promises -- that EINTR really and truly can happen at any time whatsoever -- and you won't be surprised when it happens during a different situation (suspend/resume cycle, transient fault, &c).

Answer (score 0):

(Replaces earlier comments.)

First,

```
$0 $line &
```

should be

```
"$0" "$server" "$line" &
```

because the producer code expects `$1` to be the FIFO's name.  The double-quotes are in case anything in `$0`, `$server`, or `$line` includes spaces or other special (to bash) characters.

On cygwin, I was able to test the code by manually running `foo.sh` in one terminal and `foo.sh serwerfifo 4` in a separate terminal. However, I could not reproduce the "interrupted system call." I did, however, get an infinite loop of doubling values in the `foo.sh` terminal.  Was that the intention?  The reason is that every call of `$0 ... &` produces another line of output for `read` to consume, whereupon the consumer side calls `$0 ... &` again, producing another line of output ...